# Why am i receiving Incorrect syntax near 'CAST' when assigning to an identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am recieveing the following error

> ```
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
> ```

When I execute the code below:

```
SET @BrandMarket = CONCAT(
   '(CAST((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [2018].[dbo].[USA19SoybeanTraitRawData] WHERE [2018].[dbo].[USA19SoybeanTraitRawData].[', 
   @BrandCol, 
   '] = ', 
   @CodeID, 
   ') AS FLOAT)*100) / CAST((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [2018].[dbo].[USA19SoybeanTraitRawData] WHERE [2018].[dbo].[USA19SoybeanTraitRawData].[',
   @BrandCol, 
   '] IS NOT NULL) AS FLOAT)'
   );
```

I the expect to execute the Select statement by:

```
INSERT @BrandMarketCodePer EXECUTE (@BrandMarket);
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: When I run your first code block I get no error (after adding required `declares`). I guess you are getting the error when you run the second code block? The second code block is definitely not going to work.

Comment: If you are trying to insert into a table based on selects using parameters, there are better and easier ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should always provide the DBMS name to got a proper and faster response as each DBMS has their own version of SQL except the basic SQL commands. Going by your code, I guessed that your DBMS was probably SQL Server.

1. A CAST statement on its own is not an executable command. You have a missing SELECT. -->  this was your reason of the error.
2. You do not need to provide the table name in your where clause when you have only one table used in your query. If you are using more than one table, you should try using an alias name for each table to make the code better readable. <-- this was not source of the error, but a recommendation.
3. I also removed a few unnecessary parenthesis and indented the code properly for better readability.

You can try this way (if your DBMS is SQL Server):

```
SET @BrandMarket = CONCAT('SELECT                            
                              CAST(
                                    (
                                      SELECT COUNT (*) 
                                      FROM   [2018].[dbo].[USA19SoybeanTraitRawData] 
                                      WHERE  [', @BrandCol, '] = ', @CodeID, '
                                    ) AS FLOAT
                                  )*100

                             / 
                              CAST(
                                    (
                                       SELECT COUNT (*) 
                                       FROM   [2018].[dbo].[USA19SoybeanTraitRawData] 
                                       WHERE  [', @BrandCol, '] IS NOT NULL
                                    ) AS FLOAT
                                  )
                            '
                         );
```

Comment: This is an injection problem too. The injected values need to be properly quoted.

Comment: @Larnu I tried to cater to the main error at hand without deviating much away from original code. But yes, agree to your point.